# Beginner to C. Starting a gradebook application

Tags: c

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(void) {
    int numStudents;
    int i = 0 ;

    printf("How many students are in your class? \n");
    scanf("%d", &numStudents);

    int grade[numStudents];

    while ( i > numStudents ){
        scanf("%d", &grade[i]);
        printf("\n");
        i++;
    }
}
```

what i want it to do is just get the number of students and allow that many scanners to get grades. Thanks.

Comment: Use code formatting (4 spaces before each line, or highlight it all and click the `{}` button in the UI) to make your code readable. Then tell us exactly where you're stuck and what you've tried and ask a question, rather than just telling us what you need done.

Comment: Plus, you might want to change `while( i > numStudents )` to `while( i < numStudents )` or you will be frustrated as to why the loop never runs. Maybe this is actually your problem. If so, please tell us.

Answer (score 4):

```
while ( i > numStudents ){
    scanf("%d", &grade[i]);
    printf("\n");
    i++;
}
```

Your `while` condition is backwards; the loop body will never execute.

Answer (score 1):

Two main issues with your code.  First, you either have to know the size of the array `grade` at compile time, or you have to allocate it once you know how much you want.

For example:

```
#define MAX_STUDENTS 100
    int grade[MAX_STUDENTS];

    scanf("%d", &numStudents);
    if ( numStudents > MAX_STUDENTS ) {
        printf("Sorry, cannot handle %d students, I can only handle %d\n",
               numStudents, MAX_STUDENTS);
        exit(1);
    }
```

Or:

```
    int *grade;
    grade = malloc(sizeof(int) * numStudents);
    if ( !grade ) {
        printf("Failed to allocate memory for grades\n");
        exit(1);
    }
```

The other problem is your `while` loop.  You want to iterate while `i < numStudents`.

Comment: C99 VLAs allow `int grade[numStudents];`

Comment: I threw that in just in case he was using an older compiler.  Also, if he's just learning C, it's a bad habit to get into without understanding all of the pitfalls.

Comment: You can bite yourself in many ways in C. Many things have pitfalls. Might as well learn how to use it.

Answer (score 1):

```
while ( i > numStudents ){
    scanf("%d", &grade[i]);
    printf("\n");
    i++;
}
```

`i` is `0` at first ans`numStudents`is greater than or equal to `i` therefore `i > numStudents` will be false at the first check, and the body will not be executed. The condition should be :

```
while ( i < numStudents ){
    scanf("%d", &grade[i]);
    printf("\n");
    i++;
}
```

Also you should allocate memory either at the beginning of the block or use `malloc` to allocate a block of memory of required size

Comment: C99 does allow auto variable allocation anywhere within a block. It is often easier to read code written with allocations at the beginning of the block, but in this case it is easier to skip manual memory management _and_ get the exact-right-sized array as written.

Comment: but in both cases I would do a check on the max number of numStudents allowed, .... it would be annoying to have 2G students around (on the stack or on the heap, doesn't matter)...

Comment: @sarnold: yes C99 do allow it.

Comment: @ShinTakezou, I don't know about that; the program might still be in use in a decade, when universities have doubled again in size. Might as well let people solve problems to the limits of their hardware, rather than an arbitrary limit.

Comment: @sarnold secure software does limit what users can input, it is just a matter of avoiding that malicious users can exploit the breach to do evil things - what hardware and operating systems *will* be able to do *will* become an enhancement/upgrading opportunity for your software; but currently, ignoring that hardware (and OSs) is limited is dangerous.

Comment: i would always like to check the input with a limit